# Add a second JS file in Express / EJS app

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

here the link to a project I am working on to learn express / ejs / API. 
https://github.com/aspnet82/books

I would like to add a second JS file to manage clicks etc.. possibly using jQuery (also vanilla JS is ok... at the moment there is no jQuery installed).

```
// books.ejs
<script src="public/js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
</body>
```

But when I add the  tag and indicate the index.js  as source into the books.ejs file the content of the webpages is not showing anymore, is like either the app.js or the index.js are loaded at time.
If index.js is empty the ejs file is loaded properly.

What is the best way to manage events on a node / express app? For example, if I click on a element. Is this a Js file into the public folder as it is static content? and how do I call this in the app.js file?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would guess that your `express.static()` code in your server is not properly  serving your `public/js/index.js` file so the browser gets an error when trying to load that file.  You can look at the network tab of the Chrome debugger in the browser to see exactly what errors are occurring in your page.

Comment: I corrected the error, but if I add plain JS like `document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red` it returns the error "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Comment: We can't help with code we can't see (including the overall context).  That line of code should be run in the browser (where `document` is defined).  It sounds like perhaps you're trying to run it somewhere else.